# Mega menu with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu working on desktop version. But since the hover property does not work on mobile devices, how can I make it work on mobile devices?

Here my html:

```
<nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
<ul>
  <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="www.google.com">Menu 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="www.gmail.com">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="www.facebook.com">Deep Menu 1</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="www.quora.com">Sub Deep 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="www.stackoverflow.com">Deep Menu 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="www.stackoverflow.com">Menu 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="www.stackoverflow.com">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="www.stackoverflow.com">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="www.stackoverflow.com">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="www.stackoverflow.com">Sub Menu 2 THIS IS SO LONG IT MIGHT CAUSE AN ISSEUE BUT MAYBE NOT?</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="www.stackoverflow.com">Category 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="www.stackoverflow.com">Category 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="www.stackoverflow.com">Category 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="www.stackoverflow.com">Category 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="www.stackoverflow.com">Category 5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="www.stackoverflow.com">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="www.stackoverflow.com">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="www.stackoverflow.com">Menu 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="www.stackoverflow.com">Menu 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Here my css:

```
#primary_nav_wrap
{
    margin-top:15px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul
{
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul a
{
    display:block;
    color:#333;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:700;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:32px;
    padding:0 15px;
    font-family:"HelveticaNeue","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li
{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li.current-menu-item
{
    background:#ddd
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover
{
    background:#f6f6f6
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul
{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    background:#fff;
    padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li
{
    float:none;
    width:200px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a
{
    line-height:120%;
    padding:10px 15px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul
{
    top:0;
    left:100%
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul
{
    display:block
}
```

My jquery is way too limited and I hope you can help with.

[Here is a pen](http://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/jBzJLr)

Comment: You can use `twitter-bootstrap`.

Comment: Unfortunately it is for a site that is already done in WordPress. my snippet is just an example.

Comment: Try http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KWoERa , I removed hover function so you can try it

Comment: @Carsten Løvbo Andersen. Links are not working

Comment: @Ragmah Link works just fine for me.

Comment: @Ragmah  The link works perfectly in my mobile chrome and mobile safari.

Comment: The e.preventDefault(); prevents de redirection, which means that when you click on a menu item it will not redirect.